# How to set default printer in asp.net?

Tags: asp.net, printing, printdocument

I want to set a default printer to print the docs from my web application. I don't know how to set it. As all the users using this application should have a specific printter accttached to their PC. Please help me. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Description

#### You can't set the default printer of a user who visits your site.

#### If you want to set your own default printer programmatically you can use the following function.

```
[DllImport("winspool.drv", CharSet=CharSet.Auto, SetLastError=true)]
public static extern bool SetDefaultPrinter(string Name);
```

#### More Information

- [SetDefaultPrinter (winspool)](http://www.pinvoke.net/default.aspx/winspool/SetDefaultPrinter.html)

Comment: Sir if i know that the all users using my app. have a specific printer installed in their PC then can we go for it???

Comment: What is **your App** ? If it is a WebApplication it is not possible.

Comment: Than it is not possible. There is no standard defined to get access to the system by an web application. So my anwers is right.